# mlflow dowload artifact too many 500 error responses

Tags: mlflow

i want to download artifact from remote server i used for mlflow tracking with below code  :

> 

```
from mlflow.tracking import MlflowClient
import pandas as pd
import mlflow
uri="http://some_url"
ex_id = '1'

mlflow.set_tracking_uri(uri)
experiments = mlflow.list_experiments()
runs = mlflow.search_runs(ex_id)
runs=runs[runs['tags.dataset'] == 'my_dataset']




client = MlflowClient()
client.download_artifacts("c21d2c4e75c047608003235f213e5bb5", "myarts/arts.csv", dst_path="./local_arts/")
```

but after a minute it give me below error :

> The following failures occurred while downloading one or more artifacts from http://some_url/api/2.0/mlflow-artifacts/artifacts/1/c21d2c4e75c047608003235f213e5bb5/artifacts: {'myarts/': 'MlflowException("API request to http://some_url/api/2.0/mlflow-artifacts/artifacts/1/c21d2c4e75c047608003235f213e5bb5/artifacts/myarts/ failed with exception HTTPConnectionPool(host='some_url', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/mlflow-artifacts/artifacts/1/c21d2c4e75c047608003235f213e5bb5/artifacts/myarts/ (Caused by ResponseError('too many 500 error responses'))")'}

what is wrong with it ?

i upgraded mlflow but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was not able to find the artifact which I was trying to download, once I correctly specified the name it executed successfully